# R Combinatoric Sequence Generation

Tags: r, math

I am attempting to generate a matrix where each column represents a sequence of factors in R. The factors can assume the values 1, 2, 3 or 4. Each sequence has 13 elements suggesting a total of 4^13 potential sequences. However, only a specific subset of these potential sequences are considered valid. The logic is as follows:

1. A sequence can start at any factor
2. If a sequence starts at 4, its second element can be less than or equal to 4
3. Once an element drops below 4, subsequent entries must be weakly increasing
4. If a sequence starts with 1, 2, or 3 it must be weakly increasing

So for example, the sequence (1,2,3,3,3.....3) is valid. The sequence (4,4,1,1,2,4,4....4) is also valid. The sequence (4,1,2,3,1,1....1) is not, since it is not weakly increasing after the first drop from 4 to 1.

At the moment, I have code to combine the 2&3 factors and generate this matrix. The process involves generating a matrix of all possible sequences and then filtering down based on the above logic. This is highly inefficient, but I can post it if necessary. This process also cannot be generalized to a four factor model, as the 4^13 potential sequences overwhelm my machine.

If any of you can offer insight into how I might generate these valid sequences, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that once a gradually increasing vector reaches 4, it cannot jump back down again to a lower value the way that it can if 4 is the first number (if it can, the code is actually easier).

The following function generates compatible sequences, essentially using `switch` to implement a Markov chain

```r
generate_seq <- function(n)
{
  x    <- numeric(n)
  x[1] <- sample(4, 1)
  had_a_four <- FALSE
  
  for(i in seq(n - 1)) {
    if(!had_a_four)
    {
      x[i + 1]  <- switch(x[i], sample(1:2, 1, prob = c(3, 1)), 
                                sample(2:3, 1, prob = c(3, 1)), 
                                sample(3:4, 1, prob = c(3, 1)), 
                                sample(4, 1))
    }
    else
    {
      x[i + 1]  <- switch(x[i], sample(1:2, 1, prob = c(3, 1)), 
                                sample(2:3, 1, prob = c(3, 1)), 
                                sample(3:4, 1, prob = c(3, 1)),  
                                4)
    }
   if(x[i + 1] == 4 & !all(x[1:(i+1)] == 4)) had_a_four <- TRUE
  }
  x
}
```

And we can generate a 4-column matrix like this:

```
set.seed(4)
matrix(replicate(4, generate_seq(13)), ncol = 4)
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#>  [1,]    4    4    1    1
#>  [2,]    3    3    1    2
#>  [3,]    3    4    2    3
#>  [4,]    3    4    2    3
#>  [5,]    4    4    2    4
#>  [6,]    4    4    3    4
#>  [7,]    4    4    3    4
#>  [8,]    4    4    3    4
#>  [9,]    4    4    4    4
#> [10,]    4    4    4    4
#> [11,]    4    4    4    4
#> [12,]    4    4    4    4
#> [13,]    4    4    4    4
```

Comment: This is excellent Allan, thank you! I can generate a large number of columns and then remove duplicates to obtain an exhaustive collection of sequences. I can save that as a .csv and just call that file when needed.

Comment: I don't think this is correct as it fails to take into account that the sequence can drop after the second element if the second element is a 4 (i.e. OP stated that `(4,4,1,1,2,4,4....4)` is a valid sequence).

Comment: That is correct, a sequence can drop once provided all antecedent elements are 4s. So, for example if the first 5 elements of a sequence are all 4s, then the sixth element could be 1, 2, 3, or 4. Once a sequence drops from a 4, the remaining elements must be weakly increasing.

Comment: @27ϕ9 Thanjs - I think I missed that. However, this doesn't make any of the sequences the function produces wrong; it just means it misses out on a small proportion of the sample space. Changing `if(x[i + 1] == 4)` to `if(x[i + 1] == 4 & !all(x == 4))` fixes this.

Comment: Yes, sorry, wasn't implying that the sequences generated were wrong, just that it couldn't be used to generate an exhaustive list like OP seems to want.

Comment: @27ϕ9 not at all - thanks for your input. This was more a way of generating some random compatible sequences. I do like your more exhaustive approach.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `RcppAlgos` to do this efficiently by generating the combinations for vectors of length 1:n (where it's assumed that the shorter vectors are left padded to length 13 with `4`) :

```
library(RcppAlgos)

get_combos <- function(n) {
  unique(do.call(rbind, sapply(rev(seq(n)), function(x)
    do.call(
      cbind, c(rep(4, n - x), list(comboGeneral(1:4, x, TRUE)))
    ))))
}

res <- get_combos(13)

head(res)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     2
[3,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     3
[4,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     4
[5,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     2     2
[6,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     2     3

nrow(res)
[1] 2367
```